# ggVennDiagram, define decimal places

Tags: r, ggplot2

does someone have an idea how to change the number of displayed decimal places when using the ggVennDiagram function (R)?

```
# Example code
install.packages("ggVennDiagram")
my_species <- paste("species", 1:50, sep="")
set.seed(2)
x <-list(A = sample(my_species, 12), 
         B = sample(my_species, 20), 
         C = sample(my_species, 16),
         D = sample(my_species, 2))

# venn plot
ggVennDiagram(x, label="percent") +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(), 
        legend.position = "none",
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank())
```

From the source code (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggVennDiagram/versions/0.3/source), I see that the author defined two decimal places for label="percent".
Can I overwrite this in my R code, so that I have either no decimal places or just one?

```
# from function "plot_venn()" in source code of ggVennDiagram 
counts <- counts %>%
  mutate(percent=paste(round(.data$count*100/sum(.data$count),digits = 2),"%",sep=""))
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ggVennDiagram` now support percent_digit configuration in version 1.1. You may update it and set percent_digit as followings:

```r
ggVennDiagram(x, label_percent_digit = 1, label = "percent")
```

see https://venn.bio-spring.info/using-ggvenndiagram#setting-region-label for more information.

Answer (score 2):

There is always a solution, but since this is hard coded way down, its going to get ugly.

In this case one way to do it is to initialise the figure without percentages, then add them yourself like ggVennDiagram would have, which requires a bit of backtracking through code and reaching into its innards.

```r
g <- ggVennDiagram(x, label=NULL) +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank())
g

## Notice label=NULL above. We add labels ourself like so:

region_data <- ggVennDiagram:::four_dimension_ellipse_regions(n.sides=3000)
counts <- ggVennDiagram:::four_dimension_region_values(x)
polygon <- region_data[[1]]
center <- region_data[[2]]
counts <- counts %>%
    mutate(percent=paste(round(.data$count*100/sum(.data$count),digits = 1),"%",sep="")) %>%
    mutate(label = paste(.data$count,"\n","(",.data$percent,")",sep=""))
data <- merge(counts,center)

g + geom_label(aes_string(label="percent"),data=data,label.size = NA, alpha=.5)
```

(note, the code above was just copied from the package itself, the work goes into reverse engineering and figuring out which bits you need, and in which order)

You should notify the author of the package of this need, and ask him to offer this as a function argument.